# Listiview Item not highlighting when hovering over - UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: xaml, listview, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a UserControl used as an item template in a ListView and when I hover a specific item it doesn't highlight it yet I have other ListViews in my project where the specific item is highlighted over.

I've removed the code from my UserControl and copy/pasted it directly in my DataTemplate to check if it was related to the fact that I was using a UserControl but no difference.

This ListView is contained in a SemanticZoom, so again I removed the SemanticZoom to check if the behaviour would change, but to no avail! Still doesn't get highlighted.

All my ListViews have their SelectionMode set to Single and I've got a style defined at the app level which is applied to all my ListViews

This is the code in my UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.UserControls.ZoomedIn"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyApp.UserControls"
    xmlns:converters="using:MyApp.Converters"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="470">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <converters:WrapOnConverter x:Key="WrapOnConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="Details" 
          Background="White" 
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Grid.Row="0"
          Margin="12,5,12,5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="Image" 
               Source="{Binding Image}" 
               Width="100" 
               Height="100" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill" 
               Grid.Row="0" 
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.RowSpan="2" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Image x:Name="Image2" 
               Source="{Binding Image2}" 
               Width="30" 
               Height="30" 
               Margin="67,67,0,0" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill" 
               Grid.Row="0" 
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.RowSpan="2" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Image x:Name="Image3" 
               Source="{Binding Image3}" 
               Width="30" 
               Height="30" 
               Margin="32,67,0,0" 
               Stretch="UniformToFill" 
               Grid.Row="0" 
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.RowSpan="2" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />        
        <StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0" 
                    Grid.Row="0" 
                    Grid.Column="1" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock x:Name="Title" 
                       Text="{Binding Title}" 
                       Foreground="{ThemeResource
                       SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       TextWrapping="{Binding 
                       Converter={StaticResource WrapOnConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Time" 
                       Text="{Binding Time}" 
                       Foreground="DarkCyan" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Margin="0,5,0,5" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="Description"
                       Text="{Binding Description}" 
                       Foreground="Black" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       MaxLines="2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And my ListView is defined as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsDetails}}"
          SelectionMode="Single"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedDetailIndex}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetail, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <usercontrols:ZoomedIn DataContext="{Binding}" />
              </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <ListView.GroupStyle>
              <GroupStyle>
                  <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBlock FontSize="20" 
                                     Text="{Binding CategoryName}" 
                                     Foreground="{ThemeResource
                                     SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush}" 
                                     FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
              </GroupStyle>
          </ListView.GroupStyle>
          <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
              <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                  <Core:InvokeCommandAction 
                      Command="{Binding ItemClickCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDetail}" />
              </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
          </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </ListView>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why one ListView would be behaving differently to the others?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item is not highlighted because you have the `Background="White"` set, and this color will always be above the highlight color. The `UserControl` background needs to be set to `Transparent`.

To make it work the way you want, you need to change the `ItemContainerStyle` of your `ListView`. If you have different elements in your `ListView` you can use `ItemContainerStyleSelector`.

You can read more about `ListViewItem` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx).

You need the change the `Background` property of list view items, for example:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Spot on!! I set the background color to debug UI issue and forgot to remove it from my user control. Many thanks!